# How to get data from child in Python

Tags: python

I'm learning python. I can't get data from child line(MARKET). How to get "owner" data?

```
"data": [
   {
        "property": "car",
        "sale": "bus",
        "market": [
            {
             "owner": "John",
```

my code is:

```
r = requests.get('https:/.........
for article in r["data"]:
  print("Property",article["property"])
  print("Sale",article["sale"])
  print("Collection",article["owner"])
```

Everything else is ok, but I can't get data from "owner".

```
print("Collection :",article["owner"])
KeyError: 'owner'
```

Comment: `article["market"][0]["owner"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data in a nested dictionary/list structure like this:

```py
article['market'][0]['owner']
```

I'll break down each piece to hopefully show a bit better how this works

```py
article['market']
# "market": [
#            {
#             "owner": "John",
#              ...


article['market'][0]
#  {
#   "owner": "John",
     ...
#  }

article['market'][0]['owner']
# "John"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This line was a solution: article['market'][0]['owner']

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to access field `owner` in `article` object, even though it doesn't have it. The `owner` field is located in `article["market"][index]["owner"]`. `market` here represents an array, so you might want to iterate over it with another for loop or simply access the first element in it, then in the above-mentioned code `index = 0`.